# Ordered field of Polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, ordered-fields

List the following functions from smallest to largest.

$$\frac{x^2 + 2}{x-1},\frac{x^2 - 2}{x+1},\frac{x + 1}{x^2-2},\frac{x + 2}{x^2-1}$$

To solve the problem, I believe we compare each fraction with each other. In order to figure out if a number is bigger than another number, we can subtract the numbers from each other, and see if they are bigger than zero (positive, negative). For example:

$$If A < B \enspace , \enspace 0 < B - A.$$

The same thing is applied to the polynomials, for instance:

$$\frac{x^2 + 2}{x-1} - \frac{x^2 - 2}{x+1} = \frac{2x^2 + 4x}{(x-1)(x+1)} > 0$$

Because the leading coefficient is the same sign, the value is always positive, therefore 
$$\frac{x^2 + 2}{x-1} > \frac{x^2 - 2}{x+1}$$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Alternately $a/b \ge c/d$ if $ad \ge bc$ gives the ordering, assuming the obvious ordering of polynomials.

Comment: To begin with: what does it mean that function $\;f\;$ is bigger than function $\;g\;$ ? Maybe that $\;f(x)\ge g(x)\;\;\forall\,x\in D\;,\;\;D:=\;$ the common definition domain of $\;f,g\;$ , or what?